# Button that navigates to internet page (Windows Phone App 8.0)

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I've tried with hyperlink button, but it's not working. How to write a code for app that has button, and when you click that button, your app navigates you to the internet page (for example Facebook button that leads to Facebook page)?

Comment: Do you have the code here? If not then try it and come back to post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a regular button, you could always use the following code inside of the click-handler:

```
var t = new WebBrowserTask();
t.Uri = new Uri("http://www.yoursite.com", UriKind.Absolute);
t.Show();
```

You can also read more:

[How to use the web browser task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)